# error C2039: 'get_quest_dynstr' : is not a member of '`global namespace'

Tags: c++, oop

I get this error

> Error 2   error C2039: 'get_quest_dynstr' : is not a member of '`global
>   namespace''   e:\phase3a\tdisk\workspace\cbs\source\cbs\schedapp\source\treesearchbox.cpp 17  1   SchedApp
>
> Error 3   error C2039: 'CheckCommand' : is not a member of '`global
>   namespace''   e:\phase3a\tdisk\workspace\cbs\source\cbs\schedapp\source\treesearchbox.cpp 21  1   SchedApp

When I try to compile my C++ application.

**TreeSearchBox.hpp**

```
#if !defined(TREE_SEARCH_BOX)
#define TREE_SEARCH_BOX

#include "standaloneconn.hpp"

class TREE_SEARCH_BOX : public STANDALONE_CONN
{
public: 
    TREE_SEARCH_BOX();
    virtual int get_quest_dynstr(int idquest, LPTSTR opstr, PDYNOBJ dynpobj);
    virtual int CheckCommand(PBASEWND pwnd, int idItem, HWND hwndCtl, int wNotifyCode, int indx);
    virtual LPTSTR  get_classname(){return _TEXT("TREE_SEARCH_BOX");}
};

#endif
```

**TreeSearchBox.cpp**

```
#include "cpptot.hpp"
#include "apptot.hpp"
#include "TreeSearchBox.hpp"
#include "lov.hpp"


//******************************************************************************
// Component: IFS/Scheduling
//
// File name: TreeSearchBox.cpp
// 
// Purpose:   Contains an object for connecting a standalone client directly to ORACLE
//              
// Ver          Date        Sign    History
// ---          ----        ----    -------
//              150604      FARFLK  Adding tree search functioanlity enhanced
//******************************************************************************    
int TREE_SEARCH_BOX::get_quest_dynstr(int idquest, LPTSTR opstr, PDYNOBJ dynpobj){
    return 0;//get_quest_dynstr(idquest, opstr, dynpobj);
}

int TREE_SEARCH_BOX::CheckCommand(PBASEWND pwnd, int idItem, HWND hwndCtl, int wNotifyCode, int indx){
    return 0;
}
```

I'm struggling for a long time on how to rectify this error. Please help me. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: maybe you are missing some required include

Comment: What's at line 17 and 22? You're not showing these.

Comment: Those are plain comments. i added them to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the beginning you have a *guard block*:

```
#if !defined(TREE_SEARCH_BOX)
#define TREE_SEARCH_BOX
```

which is good. But it does mean you call `#define TREE_SEARCH_BOX` which means `TREE_SEARCH_BOX` is defined as nothing. So when you compile, your preprocessor scans your files, and replaces `TREE_SEARCH_BOX` with . This is breaking your code, because you're now trying to compile this:

```
int ::get_quest_dynstr(int idquest, LPTSTR opstr, PDYNOBJ dynpobj){ ...
```

Where the :: means `global namespace`.

There are two ways to fix this:

- change your guard block

  ```
   #if !defined(TREE_SEARCH_BOX_SOMETHING_ELSE)
   #define TREE_SEARCH_BOX_SOMETHING_ELSE
  ```
- change your class name.

---

What i do find interesting is that you don't get errors about the fact that you also try to compile:

```
class  : public STANDALONE_CONN{
```

But it turns out that you can define an anonymous class like this:

```
class : baseClass {

  //bla
};
```

i guess i learned something today :)

Comment: Well, it turns out that it happens more often. Just [google](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=error%3A%20abstract%20declarator%20%E2%80%98%3Canonymous%20class%3E%E2%80%99%20used%20as%20declaration) for `error: abstract declarator ‘<anonymous class>’ used as declaration`, and you'll find lots of similar cases ;) Your compiler however doesn't give this error (is it Visual c++?).

Comment: yes it is visual c++. is there are any setting i need to do to expose hidden error messages?